# Type specified in module type does not instantiate

Tags: module, ocaml

When declaring the module type `Foo` and the instance `IntFoo`:

```ml
module type FOO =
  sig
    type carrier
    val point : carrier
  end

module IntFoo : FOO =
  struct
    type carrier = int
    let point = 0
  end
```

I wanted to use point in `IntFoo` as an integer, but the following code didn't typecheck:

```ml
let another_point : int = IntFoo.point
```

I tried deleting the module type signature in `IntFoo`, and it worked. How come putting a module type prevented `IntFoo` from instantiating `carrier` to `int`, and what is the correct way to type these modules?